# ResNet50 + Transformer

Tags: tensorflow, cnn, image-classification, feature-extraction, transformer

In many papers people extract features from image using ResNet and than pass them through transformer. I want to implement the same. I want to get features and than classify them using transformer.  That's what I have done:

1. Downloaded CIFAR100
2. From each image extracted features( shape is (3, 3, 2048)) and added these features to training  dataset
3. Defined  model:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)            [(None, 3, 3, 2048)] 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)             (None, 18432)        0           input_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_20 (Dense)                (None, 4608)         84939264    flatten_2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_20 (Dropout)            (None, 4608)         0           dense_20[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)             (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           dropout_20[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
patch_encoder_1 (PatchEncoder)  (None, 3, 3, 512)    264192      reshape_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
layer_normalization_17 (LayerNo (None, 3, 3, 512)    1024        patch_encoder_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
multi_head_attention_8 (MultiHe (None, 3, 3, 512)    4200960     layer_normalization_17[0][0]     
                                                                 layer_normalization_17[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_16 (Add)                    (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           multi_head_attention_8[0][0]     
                                                                 patch_encoder_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
layer_normalization_18 (LayerNo (None, 3, 3, 512)    1024        add_16[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_22 (Dense)                (None, 3, 3, 1024)   525312      layer_normalization_18[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_21 (Dropout)            (None, 3, 3, 1024)   0           dense_22[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_23 (Dense)                (None, 3, 3, 512)    524800      dropout_21[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_22 (Dropout)            (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           dense_23[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_17 (Add)                    (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           dropout_22[0][0]                 
                                                                 add_16[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
layer_normalization_19 (LayerNo (None, 3, 3, 512)    1024        add_17[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
multi_head_attention_9 (MultiHe (None, 3, 3, 512)    4200960     layer_normalization_19[0][0]     
                                                                 layer_normalization_19[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_18 (Add)                    (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           multi_head_attention_9[0][0]     
                                                                 add_17[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
layer_normalization_20 (LayerNo (None, 3, 3, 512)    1024        add_18[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_24 (Dense)                (None, 3, 3, 1024)   525312      layer_normalization_20[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_23 (Dropout)            (None, 3, 3, 1024)   0           dense_24[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_25 (Dense)                (None, 3, 3, 512)    524800      dropout_23[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_24 (Dropout)            (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           dense_25[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_19 (Add)                    (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           dropout_24[0][0]                 
                                                                 add_18[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
layer_normalization_21 (LayerNo (None, 3, 3, 512)    1024        add_19[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
multi_head_attention_10 (MultiH (None, 3, 3, 512)    4200960     layer_normalization_21[0][0]     
                                                                 layer_normalization_21[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_20 (Add)                    (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           multi_head_attention_10[0][0]    
                                                                 add_19[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
layer_normalization_22 (LayerNo (None, 3, 3, 512)    1024        add_20[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_26 (Dense)                (None, 3, 3, 1024)   525312      layer_normalization_22[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_25 (Dropout)            (None, 3, 3, 1024)   0           dense_26[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_27 (Dense)                (None, 3, 3, 512)    524800      dropout_25[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_26 (Dropout)            (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           dense_27[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_21 (Add)                    (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           dropout_26[0][0]                 
                                                                 add_20[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
layer_normalization_23 (LayerNo (None, 3, 3, 512)    1024        add_21[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
multi_head_attention_11 (MultiH (None, 3, 3, 512)    4200960     layer_normalization_23[0][0]     
                                                                 layer_normalization_23[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_22 (Add)                    (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           multi_head_attention_11[0][0]    
                                                                 add_21[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
layer_normalization_24 (LayerNo (None, 3, 3, 512)    1024        add_22[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_28 (Dense)                (None, 3, 3, 1024)   525312      layer_normalization_24[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_27 (Dropout)            (None, 3, 3, 1024)   0           dense_28[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_29 (Dense)                (None, 3, 3, 512)    524800      dropout_27[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_28 (Dropout)            (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           dense_29[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_23 (Add)                    (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           dropout_28[0][0]                 
                                                                 add_22[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
layer_normalization_25 (LayerNo (None, 3, 3, 512)    1024        add_23[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
multi_head_attention_12 (MultiH (None, 3, 3, 512)    4200960     layer_normalization_25[0][0]     
                                                                 layer_normalization_25[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_24 (Add)                    (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           multi_head_attention_12[0][0]    
                                                                 add_23[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
layer_normalization_26 (LayerNo (None, 3, 3, 512)    1024        add_24[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_30 (Dense)                (None, 3, 3, 1024)   525312      layer_normalization_26[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_29 (Dropout)            (None, 3, 3, 1024)   0           dense_30[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_31 (Dense)                (None, 3, 3, 512)    524800      dropout_29[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_30 (Dropout)            (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           dense_31[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_25 (Add)                    (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           dropout_30[0][0]                 
                                                                 add_24[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
layer_normalization_27 (LayerNo (None, 3, 3, 512)    1024        add_25[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
multi_head_attention_13 (MultiH (None, 3, 3, 512)    4200960     layer_normalization_27[0][0]     
                                                                 layer_normalization_27[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_26 (Add)                    (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           multi_head_attention_13[0][0]    
                                                                 add_25[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
layer_normalization_28 (LayerNo (None, 3, 3, 512)    1024        add_26[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_32 (Dense)                (None, 3, 3, 1024)   525312      layer_normalization_28[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_31 (Dropout)            (None, 3, 3, 1024)   0           dense_32[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_33 (Dense)                (None, 3, 3, 512)    524800      dropout_31[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_32 (Dropout)            (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           dense_33[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_27 (Add)                    (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           dropout_32[0][0]                 
                                                                 add_26[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
layer_normalization_29 (LayerNo (None, 3, 3, 512)    1024        add_27[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
multi_head_attention_14 (MultiH (None, 3, 3, 512)    4200960     layer_normalization_29[0][0]     
                                                                 layer_normalization_29[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_28 (Add)                    (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           multi_head_attention_14[0][0]    
                                                                 add_27[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
layer_normalization_30 (LayerNo (None, 3, 3, 512)    1024        add_28[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_34 (Dense)                (None, 3, 3, 1024)   525312      layer_normalization_30[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_33 (Dropout)            (None, 3, 3, 1024)   0           dense_34[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_35 (Dense)                (None, 3, 3, 512)    524800      dropout_33[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_34 (Dropout)            (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           dense_35[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_29 (Add)                    (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           dropout_34[0][0]                 
                                                                 add_28[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
layer_normalization_31 (LayerNo (None, 3, 3, 512)    1024        add_29[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
multi_head_attention_15 (MultiH (None, 3, 3, 512)    4200960     layer_normalization_31[0][0]     
                                                                 layer_normalization_31[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_30 (Add)                    (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           multi_head_attention_15[0][0]    
                                                                 add_29[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
layer_normalization_32 (LayerNo (None, 3, 3, 512)    1024        add_30[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_36 (Dense)                (None, 3, 3, 1024)   525312      layer_normalization_32[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_35 (Dropout)            (None, 3, 3, 1024)   0           dense_36[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_37 (Dense)                (None, 3, 3, 512)    524800      dropout_35[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_36 (Dropout)            (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           dense_37[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_31 (Add)                    (None, 3, 3, 512)    0           dropout_36[0][0]                 
                                                                 add_30[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
layer_normalization_33 (LayerNo (None, 3, 3, 512)    1024        add_31[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_3 (Flatten)             (None, 4608)         0           layer_normalization_33[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_37 (Dropout)            (None, 4608)         0           flatten_3[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_38 (Dense)                (None, 2048)         9439232     dropout_37[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_38 (Dropout)            (None, 2048)         0           dense_38[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_39 (Dense)                (None, 1024)         2098176     dropout_38[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_39 (Dropout)            (None, 1024)         0           dense_39[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_40 (Dense)                (None, 100)          102500      dropout_39[0][0]                 
==================================================================================================
Total params: 138,869,348
Trainable params: 138,869,348
Non-trainable params: 0
```

You can find PatchEncoder layer here https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_with_vision_transformer/

Than I started to train model. I stopped training because got bad metrics:
https://pastebin.com/cHJjj9Lt

Should I train this model for more epochs?

After that I defined ResNet50 with max pooling. Now extracted features have shape (2048,)
I started to create dataset for this shape, but I don't know how to define model.

**I have a couple of questions:**

1. Which features should I pass to transformer model? Features with shape (3, 3, 2048) or features with shape (2048,)?
2. If I should use features with shape (2048,), than help me to create model.
   I don't know how to create first layers. Deeper layers I will copy from link above.
   3)If I should use features with shape (3, 3, 2048), tell me what I did wrong.

Please, help me to implement ResNet50 + Transformer.
I really appreciate any kind of help.

I used code from here: https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_with_vision_transformer/

Comment: Have u fixed ur trouble?